# WP ALL IMPORT imports the wrong date

Tags: csv, date, import, wpallimport

I'm trying to import data from a CSV file into Wordpress via the Wp All Import plugin.
The problem is the already imported posts have an import date.
They don't have the default time to "now".
So I have to manually change the date when publishing.
But with 5000 posts this is unrealistic.

Any ideas? :)

I contacted WP All Import support - without success
I have used the plugins for bulk date cleanup - unsuccessfully
I tried codes from communities and forums but that didn't help either.